# Implementing Priority Queue in python

Tags: python, algorithm, memory

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing a priority queue in python. Essentially I copied all the code from the [heapq implementation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) documentation, however in my application to recreate the data structure for Dijkstra's algorithm, I would like to update the priorities for each item.

```py
class PriorityQueue():

    REMOVED = '<removed-task>'  # placeholder for a removed task

    def __init__(self, arr=None):
        
        if arr is None:
            self.data = []
        else:
            self.data = []

        self.entry_finder = {}  # mapping of tasks to entries
        self.counter = itertools.count()  # unique sequence count


    def add_task(self, task, priority=0):
        'Add a new task or update the priority of an existing task'
        if task in self.entry_finder:
            self.remove_task(task)
        count = next(self.counter)  # Increments count each time item is added ( Saves index ).
        entry = [priority, count, task]
        self.entry_finder[task] = entry
        heapq.heappush(self.data, entry)


    def remove_task(self, task):
        'Mark an existing task as REMOVED.  Raise KeyError if not found.'
        entry = self.entry_finder.pop(task)
        entry[-1] = self.REMOVED


    def pop_task(self):
        'Remove and return the lowest priority task. Raise KeyError if empty.'
        while self.data:
            priority, count, task = heapq.heappop(self.data)
            if task is not self.REMOVED:
                del self.entry_finder[task]
                return task
        raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')


list = PriorityQueue()
list.add_task("A", 12)
list.add_task("B", 6)
list.add_task("C", 8)
list.add_task("D", 2)
list.add_task("E", 1)
list.add_task("A", 5)
```

The following code works fine, except it will add a new task "A", and then the old task "A" will be renamed to `'removed-task'` and keep it's index in the heap. I would prefer to outright delete the original task instead. I was confused as to how calling '''add_task"" which calls `remove_task` to change the value of '''entry'' was implicitly changing the value of items in `self.data`. I then realized that in `add_task`:

```py
        entry = [priority, count, task]
        self.entry_finder[task] = entry
```

we have these two names interning and referencing the same object. If this is the case, how may I be able to delete an object by it's ID? I think this would solve my problem, unless anyone has another solution to find the item in `self.data` and remove it in O(1). Thanks!

Comment: The built-in python heapq doesn't support deleting random elements in the heap.  It only allows you to remove the smallest.    However if you understand how a heap works and what its invariant is, it *is* possible to remove a random element.  You'll just have to write the code yourself.    Google "removing an element from a heap".

Comment: Currently, you have added an extra statement, namely `entry[0] = float("inf")` in method `remove_task`, changing the priority of the logically removed task without re-heapifying. I believe this to be a gross error that destroys the heap property invariant.

Comment: I don't believe there can be any O(1) algorithm to do what you want to do. The best would be O(log N) where N is the size of the heap.

Comment: @Booboo Actually the invariant still works. I changed to ("inf") because I thought it wasn't working and I wanted to force it to the end. Sorry about the confusion, I edited my post to reflect this now, thanks.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks! Good suggestion, I should've thought of that. Now I have the code to remove the item, but by index and my remove function looks for task names. How should I keep a record of my indexes for each entry tuple? Thanks!